# Finding a particular solution to a differential equation with a complex RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure what my guess for $y_p(t)$ would be for this particular equation.

$y'' + 4y'+ 4y = (-12e^{-2t})/(t^2 + 1)$

I know how to use the method of undetermined coefficients, but I'm lost on how to approach this because of the fraction. I realize I should combine the guesses for this solution (i.e. for $-12e^{-2t}$ I would guess $Ae^{-2t}$ and for $t^2 + 1$ I would guess something like $Bt^2 + Ct + D$) but how?

If I put them on top of one another it makes for a very messy and lengthy problem. If that's what I need to do then that's fine, but I just want to make sure this is correct before I embark on such an endeavor.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Variation of parameters.

Comment: Oh jeez, turns out that page in my notes was stuck to the previous one, so I missed it completely. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I think I can get it from here. I appreciate it!